# iOS Swift Using image.xcassets VS dropping image in xcode folder

Tags: ios

In the last 6 months I have been able to make a pretty good app in iOS Swift. But Now I want to touch upon some performance and best practices in development.

So I wanted to know what is the best practice of using images in Xcode? To be specific, I usually drag and drop images in my project folder to use it inside my app. But I know that we can also use image.xcassets to do the same thing.

The question is, which one is the right way? Or which one should be used when?

I have seen in image.xcassets we have to provide 3 images. 1x, 2x and 3x. Does that mean that I am increasing the size of the app (considering I am using many images)? Also how does it effect the performance? Is there any difference in fetching the file from project folder or from image.xcassets?

Comment: Apple strongly recommends using the Asset Catalog. See [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But can you through some of your personal views on the questions I asked? I would really appreciate.

Comment: My personal opinion is irrelevant. You should follow the official recommendations. Case in point: WWDC 2015 introduced app slimming, which selectively bundles only the assets used for a particular device when downloaded from the app store.

Answer (score 1):

On the top of my head "Image.xcassets" has a bug in Xcode 6 where you cannot load JPEG images. Other than that, it is the best practice of organizing your images. The 1x, 2x, 3x are for the different screen resolutions of iOS devices. 3x images load on iPhone 6 Plus, 2x on any device with a retina screen (iPhone 6, iPhone 5/5s/5c, iPhone 4/4s, etc), and 1x on some of the older iPads and iPhones

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense once the app is downloaded. Also, I can see the benefits of image.xcassets is for organizing and device size compatibility. But what about the app size? The 1x images i am using are ~500kb, 2x are ~750kb but the 3x images are over 1Mb and I have 6 images in my app. So would that increase my app size (download from iTunes) 6 times all the image size? Because as far as I know the app sliming is in iOS 9 which may include the feature to reduce your app size defending on the device installed. Would appreciate your comments on this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Riding.Driving In Xcode 7 and iOS 9 slimming would apply in which only relevant assets would be included when users download your app. But if you want a minimal app size at the moment, you would have to download images later, and contain your logic to only download the relevant images. I'm not too sure if app slimming is reverse compatible with iOS 7 / iOS 8 projects with Xcode 7.